# Sum of two numbers with a minimum of zero

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with two columns of numbers (A & B). I want to add these numbers together and put the result into a third column (Results).

If the sum of these two numbers is less than zero, I would like the result column to have zero instead of a negative number.

I found this list of [Google Spreadsheet function](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en),but I did not see one that is applicable.

```
*----*----*--------*
| A  | B | Results | Calculation in result column:   =Sum(A1:B1) 
*----*----*--------*
| 1  | 3 |       4 | <= Normal and good, 
*----*----*--------*
| 1  |-3 |       0 | <= Good, this is what I am looking for 
*----*----*--------*
| 1  |-3 |      -2 | <= Bad, this is what is happening.  
*----*----*--------*
```

My question is:

- How do you find the sum of two columns that will result in a minimum value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `MAX` function for this, since

```
MAX( A3+B3, 0 )
```

will return 0, when the sum is negative.

Answer (score 1):

In openoffice, I used the following:

```
 if(sum(a1:b1)>0; c1; 0)
```

This formula is placed in c1.  It says that if the sum of A1 through B1 is greater than 0 then use the answer that is in C1 otherwise use 0.

I'm just assuming that googles' spreadsheet has somehthing similiar.  I hope this works for you.

Comment: Better would be to know that in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `ARRAYFORMULA` variant:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A3+B1:B3<=0;0;A1:A3+B1:B3))
```

I didn't get the `MAX` to work with the `ARRAYFORMULA`.